# Why does pull to refresh is not working on scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uirefreshcontrol

While pulling down to refresh, the controller target method is not being called.

Why is this issue happening?

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        
        scrollview.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        scrollview.bounces  = true
        refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPullToRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
        self.scrollview.addSubview(refreshControl)
        
    }

    @objc func didPullToRefresh() {

      print("Refersh")

      // For End refrshing
      refreshControl.endRefreshing()


    }
```

Comment: try this : scrollview.refreshControl = refreshControl insted of adding subview.

Comment: All is fine with me.

Answer (score 2):

[**iOS 10 > UIScrollView has a refreshControl property**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uirefreshcontrol). This refreshControl will appear when you create a UIRefereshControl and assign it to this property. **No need** to add UIRefereshControl as a subview for scroll.

```
func configureRefreshControl () {
   // Add the refresh control to your UIScrollView object.
   myScrollingView.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
   myScrollingView.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action:
                                      #selector(handleRefreshControl),
                                      for: .valueChanged)
}
    
@objc func handleRefreshControl() {
   // Update your content…

   // Dismiss the refresh control.
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.myScrollingView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
   }
}
```

[image]